# Transferring iOS/Mac App Store Developer Credentials

Tags: macos, mac, xcode, development, mac-app-store

I'm a Mac/iOS developer, and currently have all my code and certificates/profiles on a single machine.

**I'm currently using a 500GB platter drive, but will be moving soon to a 256GB SSD.**

My drive is about 400GB full, so I'll be doing a clean install on the SSD and moving things over piece by piece.

The code is stored in SVN so that part is a no-brainer, but I'm wondering what the easiest way is to transfer the provisioning profiles, development/installer certificates, etc. to the new machine. A bit of quick Googling didn't turn up too much - is this a well-supported scenario? Or would it be best to just blow away and re-create all the keychain information?

Comment: Just transfer the certificate to the new installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd probably move my hugest files (movies? disk images?) off to an external hard drive so that my 500GB drive was well over half free, then I'd use Mac OS X's built in Migration Assistant (such as the "Transfer my information from another Mac" panel of the first-boot Setup Assistant) to move everything else onto my new drive. Then I'd hand copy my huge files (or as many as fit) to my new drive.